# Cross Account Lambda calls from Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-step-functions

I have Step Function in Account A and it has lambda which are in Account B. But on running the step function, its giving :

```
An error occurred while executing the state 'lambdaB' (entered at the event id #2). The resource belongs to a different account from the running execution.
```

Is there any way this configuration is possible.

Comment: [Has anyone done a cross-account Step Functions State Machine? : aws](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/hdbd36/has_anyone_done_a_crossaccount_step_functions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do something like this in Step Function:

```
Parameters": {
                "FunctionName": "FUNCTION_ARN",
                "Payload.$": "$"
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke"
```

and in Lambda, we need to add permission:

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "sid-1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:root"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "FUNCTION_ARN"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does this solution worked for you? with out doing any changes in step-function execution role ?

Answer (score 8):

AWS Step Functions cannot (directly) invoke an AWS Lambda function in a different account.

A workaround would be to invoke a Lambda function that calls `AssumeRole()` on an IAM Role in Account B, and then uses the returned credentials to invoke a Lambda function in Account B.

Alternatively, use API Gateway in Account B to allow the Lambda function to be triggered from an external source.

Answer (score 7):

AWS finally supports assume-role-based cross-account invocations.

- [Introducing cross-account access capabilities for AWS Step Functions | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-cross-account-access-capabilities-for-aws-step-functions/)
- [Tutorial: Accessing cross-account AWS resources - AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-access-cross-acct-resources.html)

Comment: This should be the right answer now.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes this is possible**. You will need to add a resource-based-policy on the Target lambda you are trying to invoke. The Principal should be your source-account or the role of your Step Function in source-account.
Not only invoke, there are whole bunch of other APIs that are supported in this cross-account actions from Step Function.
Check official AWS docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't vote as I don't have enough reputation point. I would say the step function can invoke lambda in a different just as "AWS_Developer" answered. We don't have to invoke lambda using another lambda, just need to give the step function execution role the permission in the lambda function permission setting.

The following setting is copied from AWS_Developer:

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "sid-1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_STEP_FUNCTION:root"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "FUNCTION_ARN"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a series of workarounds, I found the solution.

**At Destination AWS Account**

- Open Lambda Function you need to invoke through step-function, then Open `Configuration` > `Permissions` > `Resource-based policy`.
- Then click on "Add Permission" > Choose AWS Account
- Then Give Source Account Arn as below  in Principal
  `arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root`
- Choose `lambda:InvokeFunction` in Action.

**Source Account:**

Open the Step-Function and then add the following policy in the role of a Step function.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:111111111111:function:SampleLambdaForTesting"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:111111111111:function:SampleLambdaForTesting"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Let me know if you're facing any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried below scenario-

[image]

**Steps :-**

1. create lambda function in account1.
2. create role in account1 with below policy-

   **Policy:-**

> {
> "Version": "2012-10-17",
> "Statement": [
> {
> "Effect": "Allow",
> "Action": [
> "lambda:InvokeFunction"
> ],
> "Resource": [
> "Lambda-ARN"
> ]
> }
> ]
> }

**Trust Relationship-**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account2:root"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Condition": {}
    }
]}
```

3. create step function Account2 with `lambda invoke` as one state and enter lambda function ARN created in account1.
4. Add below policy to the step function execution role. Policy assumes the role created in account1 as mentioned in step 2.

> {
> "Version": "2012-10-17",
> "Statement": [
> {
> "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
> "Effect": "Allow",
> "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
> "Resource":   "arn:aws:iam::Account1:role/stepFunctionCrossAccountAssumedRole"
> }
> ]
> }