# How to invoke a step function in one AWS account from a step function in another AWS account?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a step function in an account in one region which has to invoke 3 other step functions in other accounts/regions. The invoking step function has to wait for the 3 others to complete before proceeding. What is the best way of achieving this. Is an intermediate lambda necessary?

Comment: Here is my solution (Tested), https://stackoverflow.com/a/71130182/17610082

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to go about this:

1. [Preferred] - Put an API Gateway in front of the step function, and have API Gateway directly execute the workflow: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-api-gateway.html
2. Create a cross account role - In short, if account A is the source and account B is the destination, you create a role in account B that can be assumed by account A. That assumed role has the rights to start a step function execution. more on cross account roles: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

Comment: Thank you, how does the invoked step function notify the invoking step function? If I use a lambda on the invoked side and call send_task_success() will it propogate across accounts?

Comment: if you are sending that status, you would need to do a similar...either create a cross account role that lambda can assume and send the success, or an API which wraps it.